# VsCode C++ gdb debugger not showing dynamic type

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code

Running VsCode on Linux

```
λ code --version
1.62.2
3a6960b964327f0e3882ce18fcebd07ed191b316
x64
```

The variable `myBase` in this code...

```
#include <iostream>

class MyBase {
    public:
        virtual int myMethod() = 0;
};

class MyDerived1 : public MyBase {
    public:
        virtual int myMethod() { return 1; }
};

class MyDerived2 : public MyBase {
    public:
        virtual int myMethod() { return 2; }
};

int main() {
    MyBase *myBase;
    MyDerived1 myDerived1;
    MyDerived2 myDerived2;
    myBase = &myDerived1;
    std::cout << myBase->myMethod() << std::endl;
    myBase = &myDerived2;
    std::cout << myBase->myMethod() << std::endl;
}
```

.. Is always shown in the VsCode debugger to be of type MyBase

[image]

I had expected it to print type as MyDerived1 or MyDerived2 depending on the location the program is stopped at. QtCreator and gdb does print the correct type. Here is output from gdb.

```
(gdb) p myBase
$7 = (MyBase *) 0x7fffffffdce0
# stepping
(gdb) p myBase
$8 = (MyDerived1 *) 0x7fffffffdbd0
#stepping
(gdb) p myBase
$9 = (MyDerived2 *) 0x7fffffffdbd8
```

How enable printing of dynamic type? I do have `set print object on` set in my .gdbinit which I've confirmed is read by VsCode. I've also tried calling set print object on from the Debug Console inside VsCode.

```
=thread-group-added,id="i1"
GNU gdb (Ubuntu 10.1-2ubuntu2) 10.1.90.20210411-git
Copyright (C) 2021 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.
Type "show copying" and "show warranty" for details.
This GDB was configured as "x86_64-linux-gnu".
Type "show configuration" for configuration details.
For bug reporting instructions, please see:
<https://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/bugs/>.
Find the GDB manual and other documentation resources online at:
    <http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/documentation/>.

For help, type "help".
Type "apropos word" to search for commands related to "word".
=cmd-param-changed,param="auto-load safe-path",value="/"
=cmd-param-changed,param="disassembly-flavor",value="intel"
=cmd-param-changed,param="print max-symbolic-offset",value="1"
=cmd-param-changed,param="pagination",value="off"
=cmd-param-changed,param="print thread-events",value="off"
=cmd-param-changed,param="confirm",value="off"
=cmd-param-changed,param="print asm-demangle",value="on"
=cmd-param-changed,param="print object",value="on"
Warning: Debuggee TargetArchitecture not detected, assuming x86_64.
```

Comment: Try "set print objects on" gdb command.

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem. Thank you for the suggestion. I did try that, but forgot to mention it. I've updated my question.

Comment: Oh you have a problem with the visual debugger.  I think it simply does not support this (I may be wrong).

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem. I've created an issue https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-cpptools/issues/8401